# JSP Page not redirecting to another JSP after confirmation on the alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have this code in jsp, whenever the page loads I get the alert message but after I click on ok on the alert box, I want jsp to redirect to another jsp but its not working

I have tried the following methods

```
     <% request.sendRedirect("some.jsp");%>
```

Also
         <% request.getRequestDispatcher("some.jsp").forward(request,response); %> //But I want to save cookies and session that is why would prefer not to use this

Finally I tried

```
     windows.location.href.replace("some.jsp")

     windows.location = "some.jsp";
```

Finally I was left with the following

```
     <script>

        function loginFunction()
        {
            alert("You have successfully logged in");
            windows.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Final_Project/admin.jsp";
        }

    </script>
```

None of the above methods worked, need suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies and session are unrelated to redirects; both are persistent: one on the client (cookies), one on the server (sessions).

The correct JS would be `window.location = xxx`.

A simple look at the JavaScript console would show you the JS error.

Comment: I tried that as both

windows.location = "http://localhost:8080/Final_Project/admin.jsp";

windows.location = "admin.jsp";

Didn't work